# Dynamic Multiple Fields in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I would like to capture education details and work history details of a prospective employee. How can I make these fields dynamic so that I don't have a fixed number of textboxes available but rather have an "add" button on the side so that some can add as many qualifications as possible and also as many work history details as possible.

**Education Details**

```
Years Attended | Institution | Qualification
-------------- | ----------- | --------------
-------------- | ----------- | --------------
-------------- | ----------- | --------------
```

**Work History Details**

```
Years | Company | Position Held
----- | ------- | --------------
----- | ------- | --------------
```

I am implementing my code in cakephp and I will be very grateful for any insights, tutorials or guidance.

Comment: @bowlerae, i wouldn't mind a combination of both or one of them as long as it works with cakephp. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code was originally created for a Cake project of mine. I had to convert it to a fiddle for a javascript class I'm taking so I took out a few elements (in my Cake project I allowed users to remove poll options but required them to have a minimum of two options so they would be prompted an error message if they try to remove an option when they are already down to two). I had to adjust this for my class and make it less Cakey. Obviously just change form elements to their corresponding Cake form helpers. Whatever the user inputs will be posted to an array. Loop through the array and for each input, save it to the database. If you need to know how to do that you'll have to make a new question.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <h1>Add a Poll</h1>

    <form>
    <input name="title" type="text" value="Question" size="50">

        <label>Options:</label><span class="optionOrder">Order</span><span class="optionTitle">Title</span>

        <div id="options">

            <div class="option"><span class="optionOrder"><input type="text" name="OptionsNumbers[]" size="2" value="1"/></span><span class="optionTitle"><input type="text" name="OptionsTitles[]" value="Option #1"/></span></div><div class="option"><span class="optionOrder"><input type="text" name="OptionsNumbers[]" size="2" value="2"/></span><span class="optionTitle"><input type="text" name="OptionsTitles[]" value="Option #2"/></span></div>

        </div>

        <span class='button' id="addOption">Add Option</span>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
var container = document.getElementById('options'),
    optionsLimit = 10,
    addButton = document.getElementById('addOption');

addButton.onclick = addOption;

function addOption(){
    var optionsCount =  document.getElementById('options').getElementsByClassName('option').length;

    if(optionsCount == optionsLimit){
        alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + optionsLimit + " options for this poll");
    } // END IF OPTIONS COUNT EQUAL TO OPTIONS LIMIT
    else{
        var newOption = document.createElement( 'div' ),
            newCount = optionsCount + 1;
        newOption.className = "option";
        newOption.innerHTML = "<span class='optionOrder'><input type='text' name='OptionsNumbers[]' size='2' value='" + (newCount) + "'/></span><span class='optionTitle'><input type='text' name='OptionsTitles[]' value='Option #" + (newCount) + "'/></span>";

        container.appendChild(newOption);
    } // END IF OPTIONS COUNT NOT EQUAL TO OPTIONS LIMIT
} // END ADD OPTION FUNCTION
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abcs_clients/p1ysxj35/6/